# why does comparing NodeList Elements always return true with '=' and false '==='?

Tags: javascript, arrays, web-applications, nodelist

I'm working on a 'matching card game' and storing the selected cards, or clicks, in a nodeList. When comparing the index I notice it always returns true with '=' and false with '==' or '==='. I was originally planning on using array's to stored my 'clicks' but nodeList seemed to work easier. Maybe thats just noob mistake? My code:

```
//clicked cards
function cardClick(picked) {
    this.classList.toggle('open');
    this.classList.toggle('show');
    let cardPicked = this.childNodes[1];
    timesClicked.push(cardPicked);

    let pickA = timesClicked[0];
    let pickB = timesClicked[1];

    if(timesClicked.length > 1){
        match(pickA,pickB);
    }


}
for (var i = 0; i < cardChild.length; i++) {
    card[i].addEventListener('click', cardClick);
}

function match(pickA,pickB) {
   if(pickA == pickB){
       console.log('yes');
   }else{
       console.log('no');
   }
}
```

With everything either being 'yes' or 'no' my game isn't going anywhere fast. Any ideas? (I've tried looping through the nodeList but no luck....)

Answer (score 0):

> it always returns true with '='

`=` is an assignment, not a comparison.

> and false with '==' or '==='.

That is just because the values you are comparing are different.

```js
let a = 1;

console.log(a);
console.log(a === 1);
console.log(a === 2);
console.log(a = 2);
console.log(a);
```

Comment: I understand your point.  But in my in my code: if(a = b) always returns true.  if(a===b) always returns false.  Regardless the values.  I assume its how Javascripts interprets nodes. Since 'everything is a node' (if I understand correctly...)

Comment: @ab3d_work — No. http://jsbin.com/yipafojara/edit?html,js,console,output You must be comparing different nodes.

Answer (score 0):

> I notice it always returns true with '=' and false with '==' or '==='

This is because `=` is going to assign your item to the value on the right hand side. Inside an `if` statement, it will then do a generic 'does this item exist' check. Which will always be true if the right hand side is `truthy`.

`==` and `===` are comparisons.

Comment: hmmmmmm........ Thanks for the insights.  The issue must be somewhere else in my code